# why isn't java RuntimeException called UncheckedException?

Tags: java

Why did the Java language designers use the term "RuntimeException"? Isn't this bad terminology? I mean any exception will occur at runtime whether it's a checked exception (such as IOException) or an unchecked exception.

Wouldn't it have been better if they created CheckedException and UncheckedException that both extend Throwable?

Comment: Because the guy who was assigned the job of naming the exception was RUNning out of TIME to think of a good name before the deadline.  Or not.

Comment: Also another thing to put in perspective is history. Runtime exception terminology exist well before java if I'm not mistaken. Then java appeared, took over, and extended the exception/error mecanisms...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distinction between checked exceptions (i.e. Exception and it's subclasses) and unchecked exceptions (i.e. Error, RuntimeException, and their subclasses) is not where they can occur, but where they are handled. Checked exceptions are called so because they **must** be handled at compile-time - it is a compile-time error to not catch a checked exception at some point*.

RuntimeExceptions are ones that do **not** have to be handled at compile-time (or rather, ones that are handled at runtime, by the Java virtual machine). As for specifically why they're not called UncheckedExceptions, it may be so there is adequate distinction between Error and RuntimeException, or maybe it's just because RuntimeException is what they chose to call it.

[Relevant part of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html).

*Technically you could just make your methods throw the exception up to and including `main(String[])`, but that just means the part of the JVM that invokes `main` will catch it.

Comment: Best answer I think: it's not when they OCCUR, but when they are HANDLED. A RuntimeException does not have to be handled at compile time, checked exceptions must be handled at compile time. Still I think the terminology is confusing because a RuntimeException that is not handled at compile time in your program isn't actually handled by your program at run time...

Comment: Seriously, there is nothing new in this answer ...

Answer (score 2):

The terminology isn't really the issue here, it has to do with the specific way these errors/exceptions occur, and how they are recovered from.

From the [JLS section 11.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html):

> Of the unchecked exception classes, error classes are exempted because they can occur at many points in the program and recovery from them is difficult or impossible. A program declaring such exceptions would be cluttered, pointlessly. Sophisticated programs may yet wish to catch and attempt to recover from some of these conditions.
>
> Of the unchecked exception classes, run-time exception classes are exempted because, in the judgment of the designers of the Java programming language, having to declare such exceptions would not aid significantly in establishing the correctness of programs. Many of the operations and constructs of the Java programming language can result in exceptions at run time. The information available to a Java compiler, and the level of analysis a compiler performs, are usually not sufficient to establish that such run-time exceptions cannot occur, even though this may be obvious to the programmer. Requiring such exception classes to be declared would simply be an irritation to programmers.
>
> For example, certain code might implement a circular data structure that, by construction, can never involve null references; the programmer can then be certain that a NullPointerException cannot occur, but it would be difficult for a Java compiler to prove it. The theorem-proving technology that is needed to establish such global properties of data structures is beyond the scope of this specification.

This provides such explanation as to why certain exceptions are termed "Runtime" and some are not. Checked exceptions can be enforced by the compiler, which requires the programmer completely eliminate or otherwise prevent unwanted execution.

Comment: maybe but in terms of semantics, checked also happen at runtime... right? Or maybe their catchable ability makes them actually... cought... which means they actually *don't* get through at runtime.

Comment: The fact that any exception happens during "runtime" is not where the distinction is made. It has to do with how they are handled. Checked exceptions require that you handled them in your code at compile time, whereas unchecked exceptions do not. They can happen at any time. They are also not gracefully handled using traditional exception handling methods. They are true runtime exceptions. Think about a native library throwing an error after program execution. You couldn't have handled that at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

It is called `RuntimeException` probably because one check in the compile phase and prevent it, e.g. `NullPointerException` can be prevented by checking for `null` first. 
The other exceptions cannot be checked in the compile phase. Anyway, it is just a term.